# Drawing median line from 2 points on Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, line

Given 2 locations A and B, I am looking to draw a line around the earth where for any point C on the line, length AC = length BC on the earth surface.
That is to say the line where we always are at the same distance from A and B.
I would like to be able to draw such a line on Google Earth.
I thought this was going to be easy but after an extensive research, I couldn't find any KML example to do that.